# Yii2 autocomplete CSS classes in PhpStorm

Tags: php, yii2, phpstorm, intellisense

In my projects I enjoy how PhpStorm can often autocomplete css class names etc, especially when using something like Bootstrap or similar. However, a lot of that seems to be forfeited when doing things inside a framework like Yii2.

For example, if I wanted to do the following, I won't have any autocomplete functionality on the class names.

```
<?= Html::tag('p', Html::encode($user->name), ['class' => 'text-center']) ?>
```

Is there any extra awareness in PhpStorm to get that back? Or just something you have to live without if you want to render certain blocks in an OO way?

Comment: IDE does not know that this particular array element can have CSS class names. You have to ask authors of the PhpStorm's plugin for Yii ("YiiStorm" it's called, I think) to add such support somehow. Otherwise you may need to code such custom plugin yourself.

Comment: There is a way of telling IDE that some general CSS is expected here .. but it will be a bit messy. But if you want to try -- just add `/** @lang CSS */` just before such string, e.g. `['class' => /** @lang CSS */'.some-css.class']`

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, that did the trick, although the intellisense seems a lot slower. But does answer my question.
Cheers!

Comment: Yes -- lots of Language Injection fragments makes editing and indexing of that document slower. Code completion speed should not change much though (at least that's how I see it should be working .. although with lots of injections it can bring some extra delays here as well).